# Can´t validate reCaptcha v2 in modal

Tags: jquery, recaptcha, bootstrap-modal

Actually, I have a project who requires a form in a boostrap modal. This modals have a name, email, msg inputs and google recaptcha.

I want that when the required inputs are filled and the captcha is not checked, show an error modal, and when the required inputs and the recaptcha are filled show the correct message modal.

```
$("#enviar").click(function() {
            if ($("#nombre").val() && $("#mail").val() && $("#mensaje").val() && (grecaptcha.getResponse() != '') {
                window.setTimeout(function(){
                    return true;
                    $('#modal2').modal('show');
                }, 1500);
            } else {

                window.setTimeout(function(){
                    return false;
                    $('#modal1').modal('show');
                }, 1500); 

            }
        });
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
       $("#enviar").click(function () {
        var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
        if ($("#nombre").val() && $("#mail").val() && $("#mensaje").val() && $("#condiciones:checked").val() && (response.length!=0)) {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $('#modal2').modal('show');
            }, 1500);
        } else {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $('#modal1').modal('show');
            }, 1500);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

When if ID selector´s have value or are diferent to 0, show correct popup and send the email. When fails show error modal and cancel email send with "return false."

Anyway thanks for help  ^^

Answer (score 0):

Your return is before showing the modal. The modal call will never run.
Try this:

```
function(){

    $('#modal2').modal('show');
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Don´t work. The form can send when the recaptcha is not checked. ¿Sure  the IF sentence is correct?

Comment: I was just showing you where it's not right in your code. You have your return before what you want to be done. Keep your code, just change the position of the return with the modal call.